# How to deploy to docker a flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, docker, mobile, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to deploy to docker my already built flutter mobile app. I was unable to find a clear tutorial of this exact case using Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml.
any help ???
I want to deploy it on docker and be able to use it on any mobile device by running the app container.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an example I'm providing my config file below, here is just a base setup, for more information you can read this article: https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-dockerize-flutter-apps. Please feel free to ask additional questions.

```
FROM cirrusci/flutter

RUN sdkmanager --install "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33"

COPY ./android ./app/android
COPY ./assets ./app/assets
COPY ./ios ./app/ios
COPY ./lib ./app/lib
COPY ./analysis_options.yaml ./app
COPY ./pubspec.yaml ./app

RUN cd /app && flutter pub get

WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: will this be enough to build the image, run the container which makes me able to run the app on any mobile device ?